# Sandboxed Solution to create a Document Library and enabling manual declartion as record

Tags: sandbox-solution, object-model, feature-activation, records-management, records-center

I need to create a SharePoint Feature, when activated needs to create a Document Library and then enable the manual declaration as record. Following is the code which is working fine in a Console Application but not through Feature.

[Note:- I have been using a Sandbox solution for this purpose]

```
string ListTitle = "Sample List";

string strRecordCenterURL = "URL";

using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(strRecordCenterURL))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList oList = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList(ListTitle);
        if (oList == null)
        {
            Guid nKMListGuid = oWeb.Lists.Add(ListTitle, "Description", SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
            oList = oWeb.Lists[nKMListGuid];
            oList.OnQuickLaunch = true;
            oList.Update();
            oWeb.Update();
        }
        if (oList.RootFolder.Properties.Contains("ecm_IPRListUseListSpecific"))
        {
            oList.RootFolder.Properties["ecm_IPRListUseListSpecific"] = "True";
        }
        else
        {
            oList.RootFolder.Properties.Add("ecm_IPRListUseListSpecific", "True");
        }

        if (oList.RootFolder.Properties.Contains("ecm_AllowManualDeclaration"))
        {
            oList.RootFolder.Properties["ecm_AllowManualDeclaration"] = "True";
        }
        else
        {
            oList.RootFolder.Properties.Add("ecm_AllowManualDeclaration", "True");
        }

        oList.RootFolder.Update();
        oList.Update();
        oWeb.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: what errors are you receiving?

Comment: I am not getting any errors while activating the feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation in Sand-boxed solution. Modified the sand-boxed solution to a Farm-based solution, it is working as expected.

So below is the conclusion from this post

**We cannot set the properties of Root Folder of the SPList object using Sand-boxed solution. This can be performed only by a farm based solution even though Sand-boxed solution would not raise any exception**